Single event handler in c# code for all custom buttons / MAUI .NET8
Simple ContentPage with a lot of buttons on it.  I want a single event handler (OnButtonPress) to decode which button was pressed and take a variety of actions.  Instead of tediously writing Clicked="OnButtonPress" a hundred times in the XAML, I thought (as I had defined a custom Button2:Button class anyway, for different reasons) to define this event handler as standard for the Button2 class.
Is there a way to do this?  I've been searching and AI-ing for days, and can't seem to figure this one out, so would appreciate a pointer.
I've tried:

<Style />, but events are not bindable.
adding public EventHandler Clicked = "OnButtonPress" in the Button2 class, but it cannot implicitly convert type String to System.EventHandler.
putting this.Clicked += new EventHandler(MainPage.OnButtonPress); in the Button2 class, but it complains about how OnButtonPress doesn't exist in MainPage, when it clearly does.
moving OnButtonPress into the Button2 class, but then it complains about "the type or namespace OnButtonPress could not be found" (it's like... right there, dude).
this.Clicked = OnButtonPress();
this.Clicked += OnButtonPress(object sender, EventArgs e);

The general structure of the code is simple:
namespace Adam
{
  public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
  {
    public void OnButtonPress(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      // decoding stuff goes here
    }

    public class Button2 : Button
    {
      // lotsa properties and stuff added here

      public Button2()
      {
        // I didn't put any code in here
      }
    }
  }
}

and the XAML (I omitted all the grids and other stuff):
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Adam"
             x:Class="Adam.MainPage" 
             BackgroundColor="Black">
  <local:Button2 Text = "Test" />
>



Are you searching for the How to create reusable Components in .NET MAUI?

Nope!  But thanks for replying.

So after more decades of research, I gave up trying to override the method, and instead turned to Commanding.  Which I didn't want to do, originally, because of all the extra code I had to write.
First off, I created my custom button class outside my MainPage class:
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public class Button2 : Button
{
    // stick variables in here
}

Then, I created a AdamViewModel class:
public class AdamViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public ICommand ButtonCommand { private set; get; }

    public AdamViewModel()
    {
        ButtonCommand = new Command<string>(
        execute: (string arg) =>
        {
            // Button logic goes here
            RefreshCanExecutes();
        },
        canExecute: (string arg) =>
        {
            return true;
        });
    }

    void RefreshCanExecutes()
    {
        (ButtonCommand as Command).ChangeCanExecute();
    }

Next up, I went to MainPage.xaml and added this section:
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:AdamViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

Then, in my custom button, I added CommandParameter="A0" and similar such code to the rest of my buttons.
Finally, in Styles.xaml, I added code to style the button, and also the command:
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Button2}">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="DimGrey" />
        <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3,0,3,0" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="MinimumHeightRequest" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="4" />
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding ButtonCommand}" />
    </Style>

Note that last Setter, that binds the button to my single button processor/decoder logic.
Which (sigh, exhausted breaths) finally got to the functionality I was trying to achieve - one single function to rule them all, and not writing so explicitly in the XAML a hundred times.
I guess that it's not necessary to do a view-model class, in retrospect, but at least things are working now, and the view-model is kind of useful anyway for other stuff.

I am doing the design part in C#, but you can organize it according to the XAML code. After defining a static function in the App.cs file, you can access this function from all pages. If you have difficulty in doing this, you can create a function in each page where you use buttons and write this function in the command section.
public partial class App : Application
{

    public static void btn1Cmd()
    {
        // Command
    }

    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
                                new Button()
                                {
                                    Text = "Kayıt Ol",
                                    BackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent,
                                    TextColor = Color.FromHex("#4A9EF7"),
                                    FontSize = 16,
                                    Padding = 1,
                                    Margin = 1,
                                    FontFamily = "dmsansMedium",
                                    *Command = new Command(App.btn1Cmd),*
                                },


Thanks - this got me closer.  I had a suspicion I might have to go with Commanding...
